# How to enable search function to find all values from Listview?

Tags: java, sql, loops, listview, search

I'm building an application for Android in Android Studio, and I'm trying to find a String value within a Listview, populated from a cloud-based SQL server. I'm using API 26 for Android 8.0. So far it's working and finding some values.

The issue - when reaching my last (third) activity on emulator, and inserting a string value into the search field, it doesn't find everything and the whole value.
For example, I have a list full of values (Apple, Orange, Red Apple, Grapes, and so on). When searching for product Apple, what happens, is that after typing "ap", it finds it and disappears right after typing "app". Also, trying to find Orange, it doesn't show anything when typing the first letter o.

It's like it doesn't find all the values within a map.

I've tried debugging the Loop in my adapter. It seems to correctly understand the constraint, get the correct count for 'i', and find all results containing the certain constraint.

My adapter:

```
package com.example.user.sortiment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * Created by User
 */

public class SortimentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

LayoutInflater mInflator;
List<Sortiment> map;
List<Sortiment> filterMap;

    public void performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        if (Objects.equals(filterString, "")) {
            filterMap.clear();
            filterMap.addAll(map);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        }

        int count = map.size();
        filterMap.clear();


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Sortiment filterableSortiment = map.get(i);
            if (filterableSortiment.name.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                filterMap.add(filterableSortiment);
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

public SortimentAdapter(Context c, List<Sortiment> inputMap) {
    mInflator = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    filterMap = new ArrayList<>();
    filterMap.addAll(inputMap);
    map = new ArrayList<>();
    map.addAll(inputMap);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filterMap.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filterMap.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Sortiment viewObject = filterMap.get(position);
    viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(viewObject.name);
    viewHolder.priceTextView.setText(viewObject.ean.toString());

    return convertView;
}
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameTextView;
    TextView priceTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        nameTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        priceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
    }
}
}
```

and my activity:

```
package com.example.user.sortiment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class SortimentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<Sortiment> sortimentMap = new ArrayList<>();
SortimentAdapter sortimentAdapter;
Context thisContext;
EditText edtSearch;
ListView myListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sortiment);

    Integer selectedStoreId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("store_id");


    edtSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.storesListView);
    thisContext = this;

    edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (sortimentAdapter != null){
                sortimentAdapter.performFiltering(charSequence);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });


    GetSortimentForStore retrieveData = new GetSortimentForStore();
    retrieveData.execute(selectedStoreId);

}

public void performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

    List<Sortiment> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
    if (Objects.equals(filterString, "")) {
        filteredList.addAll(sortimentMap);
        sortimentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return;
    }

    int count = sortimentMap.size();
    filteredList.clear();


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Sortiment filterableSortiment = sortimentMap.get(i);
        if (filterableSortiment.name.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
            filteredList.add(filterableSortiment);
        }
    }

    sortimentAdapter = new SortimentAdapter(thisContext, filteredList);

    sortimentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private class GetSortimentForStore extends AsyncTask<Integer,String,String> {

    String msg = "";
    // JDBC Driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    // Example 10.20.30.40:3306
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://" +
            DbStrings.DATABASE_URL + "/" +
            DbStrings.DATABASE_NAME;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //progressTextView.setText("Connecting...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... selectedStores) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            Integer selectedStore = selectedStores[0];
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DbStrings.USERNAME, DbStrings.PASSWORD);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "select id, store_id, name, ean, description from myproject.sortiments WHERE store_id = " + selectedStore;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                Sortiment newSortiment = new Sortiment();
                newSortiment.id = rs.getInt("id");
                newSortiment.name = rs.getString("name");
                newSortiment.store_id = rs.getInt("store_id");
                newSortiment.ean = rs.getString("ean");
                newSortiment.description = rs.getString("description");
                sortimentMap.add(newSortiment);
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException connError) {
            msg = "An exception was thrown for JDBC.";
            connError.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            msg = "A class not found exception was thrown.";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        sortimentAdapter = new SortimentAdapter(thisContext, sortimentMap);
        myListView.setAdapter(sortimentAdapter);

    }

}
}
```

and a part of AndroidManifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".SortimentActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>
```

Any ideas on how could I implement this search function in a better way to make it search for every string?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not using the *performFiltering* method in your activity i dont see any problems so far (in your given example you are not calling this method, so its unnecessary and can be removed). The problem with the *performFiltering* method is that you are creating a new adapter, but dont assign it to your listview, which would be bad practice i guess. You should initialize your adapter once and use it to manipulate your data in the listview.

BTW: please name your variables meaningful. In your adapter class you have two lists which are called maps. This is confusing.

Comment: Thanks. How would one replace public void PerformFiltering (Charsequence constraint)?

Comment: Just use the method in your adapter.